# How to offline install tor+obfs package

Tags: obfsproxy

I have TBB 3.62 that contains everything I need to run on openSUSE 13.1, but they can not be used in the command-line mode (no gui), how to install tor+obfs offline in terminal and openSUSE 13.1?

Comment: How will you run TBB of you have no GUI?

Comment: Reply to Tichodroma: No, TBB can not run without GUI, but I think Tor client can and I need obfsproxy to connect to Tor network.

Comment: @civos Your answer below is not an answer but a comment. If you just want to install Tor, take a look at https://www.torproject.org/download/download-unix.html.en for the official GNU/Linux repositories of Tor.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run Tor in command-line mode, Tor Browser Bundle is not necessary. Instead you can use the [RPMs](https://www.torproject.org/docs/rpms.html.en) to install Tor. Go to the [bridges page](https://bridges.torproject.org/). This page shows you some available bridges and you can also choose obfs3 here. Now open your `torrc` and add the lines you see at the bridges page. The lines look like

```
obfs3 127.0.0.1:60746 67890fea1264b5e535def1eb41e06
```

It doesn't matter where these lines are. After you copied them, save the `torrc` and restart Tor. It will connect to the obfs3 bridges now.

Comment: I don't have 50 reputation. To Jens Kubieziel: Which RPMs https://www.torproject.org/docs/rpms.html.en I should download? The web site only provide Fedora/Redhat support, I tried to download them from its repo and install manually, but says could not found, what happen?